# Create an dynamic array in class member function

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to make a dynamic array in my member function, however, it seems to create a new dynamic array each time I call the function. Is there anyway to create a dynamic array inside a member function so it doesn't remake itself.

```
class predator
{
private: 
    string name; 
    string species;
protected:
    string *list;

public: 
    predator(string theSpecies);
    void killsRecorded(string kills); // add a new kill to the end of the predator's list of kills
    string *killsList();  // return a pointer to the array of all kills by this predator 
    int noOfTotalKills();  // how many kills have been recorded

    int k; 
    static int n;
};

//The header file
void predator::killsRecorded(string kills)
{
    k = 0; 
    list = new string[5];
    *(list + k) = kills;
    k = n++;
    cout<< k<< endl;
}

string* predator::killsList()
{
    //cout<< (sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]))<< endl;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout<< *(list + i)<< endl;
    }
}
```

Above is my class and header file, void killsRecorded(string kills) should add kills to my array, however, when I try that in my main.

```
predator *prey;
prey = new predator("Cheetah");

prey->killsRecorded("Mouse");
prey->KillsRecorded("Donkey");

prey->killsList();
```

It prints out

```
Created a hunter that is a Cheetah
0
1
Donkey
*BLANK LINE
*BLANK LINE
*BLANK LINE
*BLANK LINE
```

Instead, Mouse should be in the first line and Donkey in the second. Am I doing something wrong? Also, I can't use vectors, it's for an assignment.

Comment: do not use `string* list` use `vector<string> list`. You do not need 'n' or 'k'. Use `list.push_back(kills)` in killsRecorded(), use `cout << list[i] << endl;`

Comment: Initialise `list` in constructor instead, not in `recordKills` function.

Comment: 1. make the array a member variable 2. change array to vector

Comment: @dgsomerton by the OP :do you mean to store 'kill' in the list in your killsRecorded() instead of 'kills'? i may be wrong?

Comment: @Humam Helfawi method killsRecorded() parameter is labeled as kills, but inside he uses kill, i considered it a typo.

Comment: @dgsomerton, can't use vector, for assignment vectors not allowed. PcAF@ I tried string *list = new string[5]; but c++ doesn't let me, can't use c++11 either. Karsten Koop@, how would I make the array a member variable? as in void recordKills(string kill[5]) or something?

Comment: Even a five year old standard isn't taught? Demand your money back! Anyhow, `string* l = new string[5];` works. Maybe if you provided a  minimal but complete example as required by the site rules you would get better answers.

Comment: BTW: If you are ever taught to write things like `predator *prey;
prey = new predator("Cheetah");`, your teacher is clueless. There is no reason whatsoever to not merge these two! Actually, it's considered dangerous and bad style to split them!

Comment: @JohnQuestions *can't use vector, for assignment vectors not allowed* -- What else is "not allowed"?  It would be better if you list them.  In C++, a dynamic array is accomplished by using `std::vector`.  The folly of not being able to use `vector` just leads to writing classes that are horribly broken, but you get that "A" grade from the clueless teacher, giving a student a false sense of accomplishment.

Comment: Vectors isn't in the syllabus, so for now, arrays will do, @Ulrich Eckhardt that was just me, incase I wanted to create more than 1 prey object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor, assign n a default value, say 5.  Then create an array of that size.

```
predator::predator()
    : n(5),
      k(0)
{
    kills = new string[n];

}
```

Then recordKills checks to see if there is space in kills, reallocating if necessary:

```
recordKills(string kill)
{
    if(k >= n) {
        string* oldKills = kills;
        kills = new string[2*n];

        // copy
        for(int i = 0; i< n: i++) {
            kills[i] = oldKills[i];
        }

        n *= 2;

        delete [] oldKills;
    }

    kills[k++] = kill;
}
```

It's generally a bad idea to call a variable by the name of a data structure, so I renamed 'list' to 'kills'.

Then when printing the kills, loop until k:

```
string* listKills()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        cout << kills[i] << endl;
    }

    return kills;
}
```

Remember to delete kills in the destructor!

Answer (score 0):

You should use std::vector...
to do that you have to

```
#include <vector>
```

with the command

```
std::vector<string> kills;
```

you can create a new vector of strings

with the command

```
kills.pushback(stringvalue);
```

you can add a new string into your vector "list" also you don't have to count your kills... you can use

```
kills.size();
```

to get the number of strings back.
To get the values (strings) back you can use the vector like an array

```
string name = kills[3];
```

btw: you should save the vector as a member... to do that you have to save it in your class definition (header)

**If you arn't allowed to use std::vector, you can write your own list...**

```
class list
{
private:
    node* head;        
    int size = 0;

    struct node
    {
        node* next;
        string value;
    }

public:
    list();
    ~list();
    void PushBack(string);
    string GetElement(int index);
    int GetSize();  
};


list::list()
{
    head = new list();
    head->next = nullptr;
}

list::~list()
{
    node* temp = head;
    node* temp2 = temp;
    do //delete hole list
    {
       temp2 = temp->next;
       delete temp;
       temp = temp2;
    }while(temp != nullptr);  
}   

void list::PushBack(string item)
{
    node* temp = head;
    while(temp->next != nullptr)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    //found the end of the list
    node* newNode = new node();
    newNode->value = item;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    temp->next = newNode;
    size++;
}   

int list::GetSize()
{
    return size;
}

string list::GetElement(int index)
{
    node* temp = head;
    while(temp->next != nullptr)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        if(index == 0)
        {
            return temp->value;
        }
        index--;
    }
    //index out of bounds
    return "";
}
```

I can not check if the code is correct at the moment, because on this computer is no IDE... but I think it should word ;)

BTW: you can use this list instead of an array to do that you have to write:

```
list kills;

kills.PushBack("Peter");
kills.PushBack("Thomas");
kills.PushBack("Alex");

for(int i = 0; i< kills.GetSize();i++)
{
    std::cout<<kills.GetElement(i)<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your `killsRecorded(string kills)` method is an example of how **not** to program...

- you erase list losing all previously recorded kill
- you lose the pointer obtained by a previous `new[]` which leads to a memory leak (how could you free them now your program has forgotten what had been allocated)

What should be done (what vector class does under the hood):

- define a *chunk* of slots that you initially allocate
- add the recorded strings to this simple array until it is full
- when it is full allocate another array say of twice the size, carefully copy the values from the old array, release the old array and only them affect the new array to the saved pointer
- do not forget to release the allocated array in class destructor
- and store in the class the current size (number of kills) and the maximum size (allocated size)

Code could be:

```
class predator
{
private: 
    string name; 
    string species;
protected:
    string *list;
    size_t max_size;
    size_t cur_size;

public: 
    predator(string theSpecies);
    void killsRecorded(string kills); // add a new kill to the end of the predator's list of kills
    string *killsList();  // return a pointer to the array of all kills by this predator 
    int noOfTotalKills();  // how many kills have been recorded

    /*int k; what it that???
    static int n;*/
};
```

//The implementation file

```
predator(string theSpecies): species(species) {
    list = new string[5];
    max_size = 5;
    cur_size = 0;
    // what do you do with name ?
}

void predator::killsRecorded(string kills)
{
    if (cur_size >= max_size) {  /* need a bigger array */
        max_size *= 2;
        temp = new string[max_size];
        for(int i=0; i<cursize; i++) { // copy previous recorded values
            temp[i] = list[i];
        }
        delete[] list;   // free previous allocated array
        list = temp;     // ok list is now big enough
    }
    list[cur_size++] = kills;
}
```